# Classroom API returns wrong due date

Tags: json, google-api, google-classroom

I am requesting for a list of assignment for each course. For this example I created the due date to be on the 11th but the API returns the due date as the 12th.

```
courseWork": [
    {
      "courseId": "116315138435",
      "id": "116726071520",
      "title": "Test Assignments",
      "description": "ojoijoijoijoijoij",
      "state": "PUBLISHED",
      "alternateLink": "https://classroom.google.com/c/MTE2MzE1MTM4NDM1/a/MTE2NzI2MDcxNTIw/details",
      "creationTime": "2020-07-09T17:53:00.220Z",
      "updateTime": "2020-07-09T17:53:10.544Z",
      "dueDate": {
        "year": 2020,
        "month": 7,
        "day": 12
      },
      "dueTime": {
        "hours": 4,
        "minutes": 59
      },
      "maxPoints": 100,
      "workType": "ASSIGNMENT",
      "submissionModificationMode": "MODIFIABLE_UNTIL_TURNED_IN",
      "creatorUserId": "111094682610866207024"
    }
]
```

I am not sure that I can use a time zone to fix this because it is simply returning the day/month/year without a specified time zone. Can I simply subtract the due dates day by one? or is there a more logical approach?

Comment: I do not experience this issue. Can you provide your code that you used to create the event? Doy you create a nd retrieve the course work with the same account (so same timezone)? Has the course have been created in the same timezone?

Comment: I am not creating any assignments, only reading from the api. After reading the docs I found out that it returns in UTC time, no matter the location of the user.

Comment: You are right, it's specified [here](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses.courseWork#CourseWork). I am glad you found the issue.